# Symfony 5: Guard with multiple User Providers

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use two providers (from link: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/multiple_user_providers.html), and only app_admin_provider works. The second provider is not verify. I am using Symfony v5.2. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

My security.yaml:

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\Admin:
        algorithm: auto
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [app_user_provider, app_admin_provider]
    app_admin_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Admin
            property: email
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_admin_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800
            path:     /

    user:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\ClientFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800
            path:     /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT] }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "the second provider is not verify"?

Comment: I can only log in via the first provider. The second provider is skip / not performed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggling with similar issue,

1. try to check your ACL configuration and/or debug user roles, access groups, etc. Very likely that after successful authentication **there is not enough permissions** to allow the request.
2. debug your `supports(Request $request)` method of each authenticator
3. (optional) check what you got in each method of `UserInterface` (there might be differences depends on Symfony version). Just be sure, that comparing identities (i.e. getId() === getId()) is fine.
4. (optional) check your Authenticator\Passport. Try to login using `SelfValidatingPassport()` first. Just to be sure, that it works without password.